# Angular4 routing issue

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am really new to Angular (spent over 2 years using AngularJs).
I have been watching videos on pluralsight and managed to set up a route like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ResultsComponent } from './results.component';
import { ResultsSaveComponent } from './results-save.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: 'results', component: ResultsComponent }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class ResultsRoutingModule { }
```

which works fine.
I have a bit of code that navigates to this component like this:

```
this._router.navigateByUrl('/results/' + result.id);
```

And there are no issues. For completeness, here is the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { ResultsService } from '../shared/results.service';
import { IResult } from '../shared/models/result.model';
import { IGroup } from '../shared/models/group.model';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './results.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./results.component.scss']
})
export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  result: IResult;
  groups: IGroup[];
  private sub: any;

  constructor(
    private _resultsService: ResultsService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = +params['id'];
    });
    this._resultsService.get(this.id).subscribe(result => {
      this.result = result
      this.groups = JSON.parse(result.data);
    });
  }
}
```

Now, I have set up another route. It is almost exactly the same:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ResultsComponent } from './results.component';
import { ResultsSaveComponent } from './results-save.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: 'update-result', component: ResultsSaveComponent },
      { path: 'results', component: ResultsComponent }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class ResultsRoutingModule { }
```

And again, I have some code that is supposed to redirect to it:

```
this._router.navigateByUrl('/update-result/' + result.id);
```

But this one fails. It states:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'update-result/1'

The component looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { ResultsService } from '../shared/results.service';
import { IResult } from '../shared/models/result.model';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './results-save.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./results-save.component.scss']
})
export class ResultsSaveComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  result: IResult;

  constructor(
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router, 
    private _resultsService: ResultsService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => this._resultsService.elq = params['elq']);

    this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = +params['id'];
    });

    this._resultsService.get(this.id).subscribe(result => {
      this.result = result
    });
  }

  getResults() {
    this._resultsService.update(this.result).subscribe(result => {
      this._router.navigateByUrl('/results/' + result.id);
    });
  }

}
```

I can't see why the second route won't work. As I have said, it is almost exactly the same as the former route.
I assume I am doing something silly, but I don't know where to look.
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Haitam's post, the way you are doing navigation does not exactly follow the conventions nor methodology.

```
 RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: 'update-result', component: ResultsSaveComponent },
  { path: 'results', component: ResultsComponent }
 ]);
```

What this route definition is saying is that only two routes are available, /results and /update-result.

If you want to pass the ID as part of the url, you need to update your routes to

```
 RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: 'update-result/:id', component: ResultsSaveComponent },
  { path: 'results/:id', component: ResultsComponent }
 ]).
```

Alternatively, if you do wish to keep your original routes, you can navigate to your url using the matrix notation to pass optional parameters like so

`this._router.navigateByUrl('/update-result;id=' + result.id);`

or

`this._router.navigate(['/update-result', {id: result.id}]);`

Note that the `/` was replaced with `;`. Parameters defined via matrix notation can be accessed via the `route.paramMap` observable sequence. You can read more about optional parameters here https://angular.io/guide/router#optional-route-parameters

Furthermore, I would highly suggest that you go through the docs page of the angular site, https://angular.io/docs. It has very rich content which can give you a very solid foundation.

Comment: Alternatively you can try `navigate` method instead. It looks like this: 
`this._router.navigate(['/update-result/1']);`

Answer (score 3):

Your `{ path: 'update-result', component: ResultsSaveComponent }`, route will only take in consideration the path `/update-result/`, which is not what you're navigating to.

Note that `/update-result/` and `/update-result/1` are not the same route.
What you should do is use Route Parameters, like this:

```
{ path: 'update-result/:id', component: ResultsSaveComponent }
```

This will match the url you're navigating to. More informations: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html